# Why does nslookup fail for DNS records set to a private address?

Tags: dns, openwrt, resolution, dnsmasq, nslookup

### Setup

On some networks I'm able to use `nslookup` to resolve a domain name that is pointed to a private ip address:

```
@work> nslookup my192.ddns.net
Server:     10.1.2.3
Address:    10.1.2.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my192.ddns.net
Address: 192.168.20.20
```

However, on my home network this same query fails:

```
@home> nslookup my192.ddns.net
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find my192.ddns.net: No answer
```

### What Works

I've found that if I change the A record for `my192.ddns.net` so that it points to a public IP range it will work fine:

```
@home> nslookup my192.ddns.net
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my192.ddns.net
Address: 172.217.12.238
```

At home, if I specify the DNS server for nslookup, or set my laptop's DNS servers to Google's `nslookup` works as expected:

```
@home> nslookup my192.ddns.net 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my192.ddns.net
Address: 192.168.20.20
```

But I'd like to continue to use my home router as my primary DNS so that it can resolve local network names. I'd just like it not to fail when trying to do lookups for DNS records that point to private range addresses (eg: `192.168.20.20`)

### Home Network

I run [LEDE](https://lede-project.org/) (formerly [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/)) on my home router, which run `dnsmasq`. I've looked over [the documentation for DNS](https://lede-project.org/docs/user-guide/dns_configuration) and have even setup the system so that the DNS server it uses to resolve the address is Google's (`8.8.8.8`) - but it still fails and I can't seem to figure out why.

### Question

What's happening here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature of `dnsmasq`.  The `dnsmasq` people call it "[Rebind Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding)". It defaults to being on.  Either turn it off, or add the domain that you desire to work to the set of whitelisted `rebind_domain` domains.

You can see the option `rebind_protection` if you wish to change it in `/etc/config/dhcp`. If you decide to disable Rebind Protection, you'll have to run `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart` for changes to take effect.

```
config dnsmasq
        option domainneeded '1'
        option localise_queries '1'
        option rebind_protection '0'
        option rebind_localhost '1'
```

If you wish to maintain that security except for one domain, you can simply add to the exclusion like this,

```
config dnsmasq
        list rebind_domain '/acmevpn.net/'
        list rebind_domain '/foobar.net/'
```

The attack that it purports to prevent is one where an attacker, who has taken advantage of the fact that your WWW browser will automatically download and run attacker-supplied programs from the world at large, makes xyr domain name seem to rapidly alternate between an external IP address and one internal to your LAN, allowing your machine to become a conduit between another machine on your LAN with that IP address and some attacker-run content servers.

Answer (score 1):

It is a security measure by some DNS software not to resolve to private IP addresses. I guess the rationale for this is to prevent accesses to non-secured routers.

This problem may be solved by not using one DNS which does all the resolving for you but to configure your resolver to connect to the NS for that domain itself.

Comment: Actually I suspect I once run by this on a FreeBSD system...which software, can you tell?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, sorry

Comment: Thanks! I saw on the [documentation page](https://lede-project.org/docs/user-guide/dns_configuration) `boguspriv: Reject reverse lookups to private IP ranges where no corresponding entry exists in /etc/hosts` and had tried that option without luck - is that you are referring to? If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: @cwd I encountered this problem years ago and do not remember any details; otherwise I would have mentioned them. You could run `tcpdump` on the WAN interface of the router in order to see where the problem appears.

Comment: @cwd Seen that page and boguspriv seems to be something else -- dropping RFC 1918 DNS requests that are not yours in order not to clutter the DNS root name servers with bogus requests.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro a forward lookup isn't an RFC1918 request; it's the result that's in RFC1918 address space. (The corresponding PTR would be, though.)